# Is there a way to set VS Code's terminals' base directory to root?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if it's possible to set a specific default directory in VS Code terminals (such as a cwd setting) whenever I try to open a new one (similar to what happens with Ubuntu's terminal, which starts in `$HOME` directory) instead of opening a new instance in the current directory based on the parent terminal.

I found [this information](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_working-directory) but when I changed those settings, it seems like it tries to open the specified directory appended to the current directory. It was not changing to the specified directory. I've been trying with something as simple as `\` directory.

Comment: When you changed what settings?  That article covers several unrelated topics.

Comment: this question is just about split terminals, right?

Comment: @starball this is about both, split terminals and individual ones.

Comment: @TimRoberts `terminal.integrated.splitCwd` and `terminal.integrated.cwd`

Answer (score 0):

The `terminal.integrated.splitCwd` setting does not accept arbitrary path values in the same way that the `terminal.integrated.cwd` setting does. Its description reads as follows:

```json
// Controls the working directory a split terminal starts with.
//  - workspaceRoot: A new split terminal will use the workspace root as the working directory. In a multi-root workspace a choice for which root folder to use is offered.
//  - initial: A new split terminal will use the working directory that the parent terminal started with.
//  - inherited: On macOS and Linux, a new split terminal will use the working directory of the parent terminal. On Windows, this behaves the same as initial.
"terminal.integrated.splitCwd": "inherited",
```

Trying to set it to anything other than those values should cause you to get a warning like "*Value is not accepted. Valid values: "workspaceRoot", "initial", "inherited".(1)*"